# Not able to run bower.json file - from NPM command

Tags: node.js, git, bower-install

I am working behind a corporate office. I got the download rights and I can able to download the yeoman package even bower package using the NPM command. I got the permission for download from `registry.npmjs` and `git`.

Now I am trying to run a `bower.json` but i am not able to download anything. i keep getting timeouts. Is i require special permission for to run the `bower.json` ? or I can make any config to run the `bower.json`?

attached screen shot for my error reference.

[image]

still here is the error I am getting:

```
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-rout
e failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 15.5s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/jquery.ui fa
iled with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 16.5s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-cook
ies failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 25.9s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular fail
ed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 17.1s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-sani
tize failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 23.1s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/hammerjs fai
led with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 30.5s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/jquery-hamme
rjs failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 29.9s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/bootstrap fa
iled with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 24.4s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/jasmine-jque
ry failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 20.3s
bower ETIMEDOUT     Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-anim
ate failed: connect ETIMEDOUTbower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-rout
e failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 15.5s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/jquery.ui fa
iled with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 16.5s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-cook
ies failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 25.9s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular fail
ed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 17.1s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-sani
tize failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 23.1s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/hammerjs fai
led with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 30.5s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/jquery-hamme
rjs failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 29.9s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/bootstrap fa
iled with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 24.4s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/jasmine-jque
ry failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 20.3s
bower ETIMEDOUT     Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-anim
ate failed: connect ETIMEDOUT
```

How can i come over it? any help please?

**UPDATE**

As like the sugession from Ben Diamant : I added a new `.bowerrc` file, where my `bower.json` nested, But I am getting this error: what is wrong here?

```
C:\Users\mb112830\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\bower-conf
ig\lib\util\rc.js:55
        throw error;
              ^
Error: Unable to parse D:\Projects\AMP\runtime\ui\ui-widgets\ui-widgets-web\.bow
errc: Unexpected token p
    at parse (C:\Users\mb112830\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modu
les\bower-config\lib\util\rc.js:48:21)
    at json (C:\Users\mb112830\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modul
es\bower-config\lib\util\rc.js:70:12)
    at rc (C:\Users\mb112830\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules
\bower-config\lib\util\rc.js:31:9)
    at Config.load (C:\Users\mb112830\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\nod
e_modules\bower-config\lib\Config.js:14:20)
    at Function.Config.read (C:\Users\mb112830\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
bower\node_modules\bower-config\lib\Config.js:49:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mb112830\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bo
wer\lib\config.js:3:38)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

What is wrong here, any one highlight me please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like your firewall is blocking, you need to run bower behind the corp proxy:

Edit .bowerrc with proxy configuration -

```
{
    "proxy":"http://<host>:<port>",
    "https-proxy":"http://<host>:<port>"
}
```

Comment: Do i need to create new `.bowerr` file? if so where that should be nested?

Comment: @3gwebtrain you supposed to have one .bowerrc and it need to be next to your bower.json file.

Comment: I can't have the one for the global usage?

Comment: according to bower's specification you need to have one bowerrc file for each bower.json file

Comment: Can you see, I updated my question. as like you said I created `.bowerrc` file, but getting error while i check `bower --version` - any help please?

Comment: @3gwebtrain Can you show the .bowerrc content (hide details)? It's seems like it invalid json

Comment: this is what the contents are :
proxy = http://xxxxx:yyyyy@172.18.18.87:80/
https-proxy = http://xxxxx:yyyyy@172.18.18.87:80/

Comment: You have to use quotation marks as I wrote, just change the content whitin @3gwebtrain

Comment: Updated as per your suggestion.  Now no error from bower but while do the install i am getting this error:
bower ECMDERR       Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads https://gith
ub.com/twbs/bootstrap.git", exit code of #128

Comment: i need to see the git difinition in bower.json to help you with that.
This is a diffrent issue @3gwebtrain

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57391/discussion-between-3gwebtrain-and-ben-diamant).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you investigate whether or not your Bower client is able to access the official Bower registry. Doing a `curl` or `wget` request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages and getting a status `200` response would suffice.

In case you cannot, you can review the existing available [Bower client configuration](http://bower.io/docs/config) options and configure your corporate proxy.

Another option would be to start your own [Bower registry](https://github.com/bower/registry) on the corporate network. This provides for enhanced security and high-availability of the registry, if you give it enough love.